# How to get the processor group assigned to the application

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi

I wanted to know if there was a windows API that would tell me the current processor group that has been assigned to my application. In my machine I currently have two processor groups. I wanted to know which processor group my application is running on programmatically

Comment: I'm not sure but perhaps you'll find something useful here: [`GetProcessAffinityMask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getprocessaffinitymask) and here: [Processor Groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/processor-groups)

Comment: @TedLyngmo thanks. I looked at that and unfortunately that wont really help me. There is no way for me to determine a processors association with a group.

Comment: Did you see the link to [`GetProcessGroupAffinity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processtopologyapi/nf-processtopologyapi-getprocessgroupaffinity) buried in there? It seems to do what you want.

Comment: Close to what you want is [GetProcessAffinityMask function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getprocessaffinitymask). It returns you a mask that shows on which processors the application is allowed to run.

Comment: @zx485 that doesn't tell which processor is assigned to which group, though.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`GetProcessGroupAffinity()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processtopologyapi/nf-processtopologyapi-getprocessgroupaffinity) to determine the processor group(s) that a process is currently assigned to.  A process can be assigned to multiple groups at a time, as processor affinity is set on a per-thread basis, and a process can have multiple threads.

Use [`GetThreadGroupAffinity()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processtopologyapi/nf-processtopologyapi-getthreadgroupaffinity) to determine the processor group that a thread is currently assigned to.